Navigation Controller State Management
@AndroidEntryPoint
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    @Inject
    lateinit var firebaseRepository: FirebaseRepositoryImpl
 
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        val splashScreen = installSplashScreen()
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        val profileViewModel: ProfileViewModel by viewModels()

        splashScreen.setKeepOnScreenCondition {
            val isDataLoading = profileViewModel.splashScreen.value
            isDataLoading
        }

        setContent {
                val navController = rememberNavController()
                val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()

                val context = LocalContext.current
                val credentialManager = CredentialManager.create(context)
                val googleIdOption = GetGoogleIdOption.Builder()
                    .setFilterByAuthorizedAccounts(true)
                    .setServerClientId(stringResource(id = R.string.web_client_id))
                    .build()

                val request = GetCredentialRequest.Builder()
                    .addCredentialOption(googleIdOption)
                    .build()

                    AppNavigation(
                        navController = navController,
                        profileViewModel = profileViewModel,
                        onSignInClick = {
                            scope.launch {
                                try {
                                    val result = credentialManager.getCredential(
                                        context = context,
                                        request = request
                                    )
                                    val credential = result.credential
                                    val googleIdTokenCredential = GoogleIdTokenCredential.createFrom(credential.data)
                                    val googleIdToken = googleIdTokenCredential.idToken
                                    val firebaseCredential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(googleIdToken, null)
                                    profileViewModel.googleLogin(firebaseCredential) {
                                        val startDestination = when {
                                            profileViewModel.profileUiState.value.currentUser.id.isEmpty() -> Screen.OnboardingLogin.name
                                            profileViewModel.profileUiState.value.currentUser.id.isNotBlank() && profileViewModel.profileUiState.value.pair.id.isBlank() -> Screen.OnboardingProfile.name
                                            else -> Screen.Home.name
                                        }
                                        navController.popBackStack()
                                        navController.navigate(startDestination)
                                    }

                                } catch (e:Exception){
                                    Log.e("GoogleLoginError", "Error getting credentials: ${e.message}")
                                    Toast.makeText(context, "Sign in failed. Please try again.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                                }
                            }

                        }
                    )
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun AppNavigation(
    navController: NavHostController,
    profileViewModel: ProfileViewModel,
    onSignInClick: () -> Unit,
) {
    val uiState by profileViewModel.profileUiState.collectAsState()
    val startDestination = when {
        uiState.currentUser.id.isEmpty() -> Screen.OnboardingLogin.name
        uiState.currentUser.id.isNotBlank() && uiState.pair.id.isBlank() -> Screen.OnboardingProfile.name
        else -> Screen.Home.name
    }

    NavHost(
        navController = navController,
        startDestination = startDestination
    ) {
        composable(route = Screen.OnboardingLogin.name) {
            OnboardingController(
                navController = navController,
                page = 0,
                onSignInClick = onSignInClick,
                profileViewModel = profileViewModel
            )
        }
        composable(route = Screen.OnboardingProfile.name) {
            OnboardingController(
                navController = navController,
                page = 1,
                onSignInClick = onSignInClick,
                profileViewModel = profileViewModel
            )
        }
        composable(route = Screen.Profile.name) {
            Profile(navController = navController, viewModel = profileViewModel)
        }
        composable(route = Screen.Home.name) {
            Home(navController = navController)
        }
     }
}


@Composable
fun OnboardingController(
    navController: NavController,
    page:Int,
    onSignInClick:() -> Unit,
    profileViewModel: ProfileViewModel,
) {
    val pagerState = rememberPagerState(initialPage = page, pageCount = {6})
    BackHandler {

    }
    OnboardingView(
        pagerState = pagerState,
        profileViewModel = profileViewModel,
        onSignInClick = onSignInClick
    )
}


enum class Screen{
    OnboardingLogin,
    OnboardingProfile,
    Home,
    Profile
}

in my Jetpack Compose app, the NavHost is configured with OnboardingLogin as the initial destination. However, despite logic intended to redirect to different screens based on user state, the app consistently starts at OnboardingLogin before navigating to the appropriate screen. How can I set the startDestination redirect correctly?
